# rotate labels in grid.xaxis

Tags: r, r-grid

It doesn't seem to be possible to rotate the labels of an xaxis using `grid.xaxis(at=, lab=)` by e.g. 90 degrees using a `gpar`-option.

Anybody knows a workaround apart from creating separate viewports and using `grid.text()`?

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

```
grid.xaxis(seq(0,1,by=0.1), vp=viewport(y=1), 
           edits = gEdit(gPath="labels", rot=90))
```

Answer (score 5):

Check this document: [An Example of Interactive Graphics Editing in Grid](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/grid/doc/interactive.pdf)

```
library("grid")
gxa <- xaxisGrob(at = 1:4/5, vp = viewport(w = 0.5, h = 0.01))
gxa <- editGrob(gxa, gPath = "labels", gp = gpar(col = "black"), rot=90)
grid.draw(gxa)
```

Comment: Found one - https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/grid/doc/R-1.8.0/interactive.pdf